# How to create below Gif Color Picker using xamarin forms slider or custom view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, color-picker

guys, I am trying to develop a color picker similar to attached Gif can anybody help me how to start. Or some sample available. Note I need to achieve this using one slider I know I can achieve this using three slider easily But I need to develop similar to Gif.

Here's the Link of Gif

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ecx0uw1T0JLwj3IdkDXVOM8MmPOwi-FT

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfrgC.jpg)

Comment: What you try? Can you provide some code that you have tried?

Comment: I haven't try anything yet . I am afraid I do not know how to create that gradient different color box view.Once that Different color line made . I Know I can place a circle image on above of line and move this thumb image using pangesture. I can do the pangesture part.I want the Idea about how to create that gradient multicolor line.

Comment: I find SkiaSharp ColorPickers that may be helpful to you.https://github.com/zhenweied09/ColorPickers

Comment: ahaa! Skia Sharp. Thanks alot mate @CherryBu